# JavaScript problem

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am building a website that uses PHP and JavaScript. I have a main menu that dynamically, when I click on a button it loads a page in the content div and runs its JavaScript script.

Now the problem is when I have loaded a JavaScript file and I go to another page that loads its contents in the same content div, the old JavaScript file that was included in the previous page is still loaded. Is there a way to prevent this.

**JavaScript code:**

```
$(".button").click(function(){
        $("#content").empty();
        $("#content").load("PHP/home.php"); 
    });
```

**PHP/home.php code**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(run);

        function run(){
            alert("test");
            setTimeout(run, 500);
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Homepage</h1>
</body>
```

the Jquery is loaded in the HTML that the content div is. And all the other buttons and PHP pages is being used the same way. When i load a new page the Alert function of the home.php is still going.

Comment: clear the content div before adding the new content …?

Comment: @Mkaveli: We can only vaguely guess. Could you post the appropriate code please?

Comment: We need to see some code

Answer (score 0):

just have a clue because you haven't shown enough code

try clearing out the div with

document.getElementById("content").innerHMTL = "";

then adding other page content in it

Comment: thanks but that didn't help either I now fixed it with a variable that shows if the timeout is running or not